# segueForUnwindingToViewController causing "Warning: Attempt to present <...> on <...> which is already presenting <...>"

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I am building an app and recently discovered a huge memory leak caused by traditional segues.
Therefore I learned about unwind segue. Everything works just fine if I simply use:

```
    @IBAction func prepareForUnwindToMainFromFriends(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }
```

Memory leak is solved and 'everything is awesome'. But this solution looks ugly on a UI point of view. So I implemented this function from [this website](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/03/ios-unwind-segue-custom-animation/). And changed it a little.

```
override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
    return UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController) {
        let fromView = fromViewController.view
        let toView = toViewController.view
        if let containerView = fromView.superview {
            let initialFrame = fromView.frame
            var offscreenRect = initialFrame
            var offscreenRectFinal = initialFrame
            offscreenRect.origin.x += CGRectGetWidth(initialFrame)
            offscreenRectFinal.origin.x -= CGRectGetWidth(initialFrame)
            toView.frame = offscreenRect
            containerView.addSubview(toView)
            let duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
            let delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0
            let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut
            let damping: CGFloat = 0.9
            let velocity: CGFloat = 4.0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: damping,
                initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: options, animations: {
                    toView.frame = initialFrame
                    fromView.frame = offscreenRectFinal
                    
                }, completion: { finished in
                    fromView.removeFromSuperview()
                    if let navController = toViewController.navigationController {
                        navController.popToViewController(toViewController, animated: false)
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get an error message:

```
2015-05-12 08:47:31.841 PING0.4[4343:1308313] Warning: Attempt to present <NotificationViewController: 0x177030b0>  on <PING0_4.ViewController: 0x16271000> which is already presenting <NotificationViewController: 0x1a488170>
```

And I am blocked in my app. I can go from VC1 to VC2, then back to VC2 but then I cannot get back to VC1 again. It looks like I can only use this segue once.

Any one has any idea of what is going on?

Comment: My guess is that you've messed up `push` and `present` navigation. Check them carefully

Comment: This question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421845/ios-app-crash-on-multiple-segue-at-the-same-time-going-to-other-segue-while-o maybe helpful if you want to restrict multiple segue to occure.

Comment: @Quentin Malgaud For more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560198/ios-app-error-cant-add-self-as-subview

Comment: @Quentin how did you gave segue...is from view or from button

Comment: I am trying to figure out the difference between push and present. The whole uiviewcontroller management in fact. Segues are triggered by both buttons and view. I am trying to figure out @zala solution but I don't code in objc. I'll dig in that direction though. Thank you for your comments so far.

Comment: @QuentinMalgaud the method you posted is working fine. Have you added this method to your navigation controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created Sample code for unwind segue with above transition animation code. Checkout [SampleUnwind](https://github.com/przala/UnwindSample) project that will help you to understand unwind segue(and how simple it is).

In project there is one navigation controller and inside it there are three view controller (Home->First->second).

In Home controller following unwind action is created, which will be called when 'Home' button of second controller is tapped(simple unwind stuff).

```
@IBAction func unwindToHomeViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

I have created `TempNavigationController` subclassing `UINavigationController` and set that `TempNavigationController` to navigation controller in storyboard.
Above method you given is pesent inside it as this will be container of fromViewController as per following referance.

Reference: [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-CCVC-TRANSITIONING_BETWEEN_TWO_CHILD_VIEW_CONTROLLERS) documentation about Transitioning Between Two Child View Controllers.

You can compare this with your project and maybe you can find any duplicate(or multiple/wrong) segue in your project.